# PHP - How to access a variable within a base class?

Tags: php, object, inheritance

I would like to access a variable that has been declared in a base class in the following way, can someone suggest the best way to do this, as the way I have done it below does not work?

```
class Base {
    public static $base_var;

    function __construct(){
        $this->base_var = "hello";
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    ...
}

class B extends A {
    ...
}

$obj_B = new B;
echo $obj_B->base_var; // Throws PHP error
```

Comment: It's a static var, so `echo B::$base_var;`; and change your constructor to `self::$base_var = "hello";
`

Comment: Becarefull also with this: $this->base_var = "hello"; you are accessing a static variable as if it were an instance variable. Consider declaring a static constructor or call it like @MarkBaker just said.